# Is it normal distribution problem?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I did my task and this is the solutions that I got. I think this problem is about normal distribution.

[image: this is my calculation]

Is it my calculation right?
Please correct it if I am wrong.
Thanks for any help.